# Can Google stop crawling/indexing your site because you are working a lot on it?

Tags: web-crawlers, google-index

I think I read somewhere that Google could stop crawling/indexing a site/blog if there was a lot of work performed on it (like many pages are modified, deleted or loaded daily). It would wait until the site stabilizes.

Unfortunately, I cannot find the post or video mentioning this. Am I making this up or is there any truth behind this? If Google indeed suspends its crawling/indexing, when does it come back?

Can someone clarify?

Comment: If this was true then a site like StackExchange would suffer - it does not. Perhaps if a site went through massive structural changes that suddenly resulted in a mass of 404's ??

Comment: If the site is getting modified, pages getting deleted generating 404's or even 301's etc - if site is in flux - then i think Google should wait. But a stablized site generating new content or content getting modified will be positive and important points in rankings.

Comment: What do you mean by "can" in the title? Do you mean, "does Google do that automatically", or "is it possible to make Google do that"?

Comment: I mean "does"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like get link from you read this because I think the opposite!

Google likes so much websites which are often modified because it means that websites are "alive" and Google wants to present "alive" websites on its index. I don't think Google likes present websites which didn't change for many time because they maybe aren't relevant any more.

More websites are updated and more Google like them and crawl them. Stack exchange sites like [StackOverflow proved it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84695/eeeeek-where-is-my-slow-performance/84701#84701) in the past.

Comment: From here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/webmasters/shKwyqVoEiI/N8N_N7mIzRMJ, we can conclude that no, google does not stop crawling a site, but it can significantly slow down the crawling rate if the site cannot deliver 'constant' content.

Answer (score -1):

You can put a robots.txt file in your root. You can write that in notepad or so

More about it you can find here:

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449

Comment: Ok, but that is not my question...

Comment: How does that answer the OP's question?